# How to only retrieve links from a list in Python3? [Beginner]

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

**I have list on python3 that goes something like this:**

https://textuploader.com/15dra

From this file I want to make a new list that only takes the urls from the other list seperated by commas and contained in double quotes ("), and if possible also filter all urls that contain "i.redd.it"

Here is the code if it helps:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import urllib.request
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = "https://reddit.com/r/me_irl"
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "lxml")
tags = soup.find_all('a')
hrefs = []
for t in tags:
    hrefs.append(t)

print(hrefs)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried anything at all? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @mzjn Ok thank you for the help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a list comprehension. I would also include this line:

```
tags = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

since you only want the tags with an url

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import urllib.request
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = "https://reddit.com/r/me_irl"
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "lxml")
tags = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

hrefs = [ ele['href'] for ele in tags if 'i.redd.it' in ele['href']]
```

However, this will return an empty list, as there are no hrefs in there that contain `'i.redd.it'`

But if you want the urls, you could get rid of the `if` statement, or change it if you'd like:

```
 hrefs = [ ele['href'] for ele in tags ]
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help, I'm trying to get all the URLs of Reddit posts from r/dankmemes into a list, do you know how this is possible since my code did not work

Comment: your code worked. There's just no substring of `i.redd.it` in the html source code as a href. It's stored as script in the json format

Comment: The i.redd.it links are in the script tags and stored in json format. Just post up as a new question since this question is answered and I can help you out there.